# 301 redirect in bitnami wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, bitnami

301 redirect http://example.com -> https://www.example.com

301 redirect https://example.com -> https://www.example.com

301 redirect http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com

I know how to do this in .htaccess ,but it does not work in bitnami wordpress .
help!

this is my config in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf .

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDhJy.png)

Comment: Perhaps https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/apache/ ?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the documentation:
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/components/apache/#how-to-configure-htaccess-files

All the .htaccess files are collected into a single one file in the Bitnami WordPress Stack. You can find it at `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpres/conf/htaccess.conf`. Therefore, you can edit that file an add your own rules in order to modify that configuration. You can also edit the file `/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpres/conf/httpd-app.conf` which contains other Apache rules and redirections.

Comment: hello ,juan, I follow the documentation, but it only works for "http ://www.example.com -> http s://www.example.com" .

Comment: I guess you only added the Apache rule for that redirection. Please paste your Apache configuration so I can take a look at it.

Comment: my config is in the picture above.

Comment: WordPress is missing an "s" above

/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf is the correct

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because wordpress trying to protect your website against chained redirects. When it is checking if is ssl there exist a case which is missing.
I fixed this problem by opening **wp-config.php** and replacing the code:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

with :

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https'){
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

Hope to help you too.